# Python: How do you split a string if the line starts with "ggggg"?

Tags: python, split, startswith

It seems so simple to me, but for some reason I can't get python to split properly on the following.

```
f = open('text', 'r')
x = f.read()
f.close()
result = x.split('^ggggg', 1)[0]
```

With file "text" having the following:

```
aaaaa1234
bbbbb1234
ccccc1234
ggggg1234
hhhhh1234
```

I would think "result" would contain everything before the ggggg line, but it just contains the entire text. How do I get python to split where the front of the line starts with "ggggg"?

Comment: `str.split()` doesn't take a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.split()` does not take a regex.

You could, however, use the string '\nggggg', which will match on a `\n`, if it's not at the top of a file.

Another possibility is to use the regex functions, [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `str.split()` only splits on literal text, or in the case of using `None` (the default), arbitrary whitespace. Regular expressions are not supported. Your could just split the file contents  on `\nggggg`:

```
x.split('\nggggg', 1)[0]
```

If you must use a regular expression, use the [`re.split()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).

For efficiency's sake, you could instead loop over lines, then just test if the line starts with `ggggg` and stop iteration there:

```
result = []

with open('text', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ggggg'):
            break
        result.append(line)
```

That way you don't have to read the whole file. You could also use `itertools.takewhile()`:

```
from itertools import takewhile
with open('text', 'r') as f:
    result = list(takewhile(lambda l: not l.startswith('ggggg'), f))
```

Both options produce a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not reading all the file is better, but for general knowledge, here's how to deal easily with your problem, string wise...

```
result = x[0:x.find("ggggg")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to set `result` to everything prior to the `ggggg` line?

You could try the following:

```
result = ''
with open('text','r') as f: // Open file 'text' as 'r'eadonly,
    f.seek(0) // move the readcursor to the beginning of the document
    for line in f: // for each line...
        if not line.startswith('ggggg'): // If 'ggggg' isn't at the beginning of the line..
            result = "{0}\n{1}".format(result, line) // append the line to the result variable.
        else:
            break
f.close()
```

If you'd rather make it so that it just ignored the `ggggg` line and got everything else, then try:

```py
result = ''
with open('text','r') as f: // Open file 'text' as 'r'eadonly,
    f.seek(0) // move the readcursor to the beginning of the document
    for line in f: // for each line...
        if not line.startswith('ggggg'): // If 'ggggg' isn't at the beginning of the line..
            result = "{0}\n{1}".format(result, line) // append the line to the result variable.
        else:
            continue
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python split function is not at all required. I got same result with simple string function. Apologies if you require answer strictly with lists and split function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
fh=open('text', 'r')

for line in fh:
    if line.startswith(ggggg): break
    print line

print "DONE"
fh.close()
```